# I am short and I always exclaim

Tags: riddle

I am short and I always exclaim
I vary in appearance, but only have one name
I am silent, but in your head I make sound
I am intangible and often bound

I often come with colors,
And always with shapes and lines
I serve two purposes
Of which one of them is to please the eyes

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> Onomatopoeia

I am short and I always exclaim

> almost are always followed by an exclamation mark

I vary in appearance, but only have one name

> in comic books they will vary in font

I am silent, but in your head I make sound

> by definition you make a sound when thought of

I am intangible and often bound

> words are bound to a page

I often come with colors,
And always with shapes and lines

> again different font

I serve two purposes
Of which one of them is to please the eyes

> nice fonts please the eyes of the (usual comic book) reader. the other is
>  the sound effect of course

Answer (score 8):

You are

> Exclamation mark

I am short and I always exclaim

> It is just one character long

I vary in appearance, but only have one name

> You can have different fonts, but it's still called exclamation mark

I am silent, but in your head I make sound

> It makes no sound but when we read it, we imagine emphasis

I am intangible and often bound

> It has to be bound to other words

I often come with colors,
And always with shapes and lines

> Different colors, fonts, etc

I serve two purposes
Of which one of them is to please the eyes

> Exclamation mark has its own purpose. The one to please the eyes can be some sort of notification you were expecting

Comment: However it does meet the clues quite perfectly except for the last one in my own opinion because exclamation marks do not really please my eyes on their own. < Take that as a hint.

Comment: It is also called an exclamation *point*, so it doesn't "only have one name".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you might be a

> Balloon

I am short and I always exclaim
I vary in appearance, but only have one name
I am silent, but in your head I make sound
I am intangible and often bound

> Balloon, as in cartoon drawing, usually bound to a character exclaiming something. They are intangible, silent, yet they still make sound in your head on reading them.

I often come with colors,
And always with shapes and lines
I serve two purposes
Of which one of them is to please the eyes

> Balloon, as in children's plaything, also used for decoration purposes. They come in many colors and shapes, and there's a line attached to keep them in place.

Comment: You are close with "comic book balloon". Your answer is not what I am looking for exacrly, though.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> A comic book.

I am short and I always exclaim

> Comics are often short and have onomatopoeic exclamations ("Bang!" or "Kapow!")

I vary in appearance, but only have one name

> Tons of different comic book stories/characters/authors, but all are comics.

I am silent, but in your head I make sound

> We read them, so all of the sound is in our mind.

I am intangible and often bound

> Intangible because people often keep them sealed in mint condition, and bound because it's a book.

I often come with colors,
And always with shapes and lines

> Colored illustrations

I serve two purposes
Of which one of them is to please the eyes

> We can read them for the story, but can also just admire the artwork.